# How to use properly createHash('sha1') in node.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to master a login form with the help of React+MySQL+Node.JS. Here's what I have done so far:

1. Here is my router:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const router = express.Router()
const mysql = require('mysql')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cryptoFile = require('crypto')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

process.env["NODE_CONFIG_DIR"]= __dirname + "/../config/"
const config = require('config')

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:       config.get("mysql.server"),
    user:       config.get("mysql.user"),
    password:   config.get("mysql.password"),
    database:   config.get("mysql.db")
});

    router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

        
        let user = req.body.login
        let pass = req.body.password
        let shasum = cryptoFile.createHash('sha1').update(req.body.password).digest('hex')

            
        connection.query("select user_login, user_password from users where user_login = ? and user_password = ?", 
            [user, shasum], 
            function (error, result, fields) {
                if (error) throw error;

                if (result == []) {
                    let message = {success: false, message: "There is no records for the user {user} with the password {pass}"}
                    res.json(message)
                }
                else {
                    let message = {success: true, message: {
                            user_login: result[0].user_login,
                            user_password: result[0].user_password
                         }}
                    res.json(message)
        
                }
        })
    });
```

This is the actual login form:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Login = () => {

    
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData(event.target);
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/user/login", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        });

        const res = await response.json();

        const resultSelector = document.querySelector('.result');

        if (!res.success){
            resultSelector.innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:red \">The request has not been successful!</span>";
        } else {
            resultSelector.innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:green \">The request has been successful!</span>";
        }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="http://localhost:3000/user/login" method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <div className="form-element">
                    <label htmlFor="login">Enter your login: </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-element">
                    <input type="text" name="login" id="login"  />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <div className="form-element">
                    <label htmlFor="password">
                        Enter your password: 
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-element">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <div className="form-element">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login!" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div className="result">

        </div>
    </div>
    
  )
  }
```

When I enter the right credentials, I would like to see the green text, informing me about a successful login. Otherwise I would be happy to see a red text with an error. Instead I'm getting this:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

This occurs at this line of code:

```
let shasum = cryptoFile.createHash('sha1').update(req.body.password).digest('hex')
```

I can't figure out how to use this code construction properly, so that one gets no errors. Could someone please help to find the right way here?

Comment: It would appear `req.body.password` is `undefined`,  try doing `console.log(req.body)`, what does it say?

Comment: Using an SHA1 hash for password storage is a Terrible, Horrible, No Good, Very Bad idea. Use e.g. [`crypto.pbkdf2`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptopbkdf2password-salt-iterations-keylen-digest-callback) instead.

Comment: req.body is empty! But why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `password` is `undefined`. Maintain separate `states` in the frontend and validate the input fields in the frontend itself (such as don't pass any value as `undefined` to the server).

```
//states
const [login, setLogin] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

//state updaters
const handleLogin = (event) => {
    setLogin(event.target.value);
}

const handlePassword = (event) => {
    setPassword(event.target.value);
}
```

```
//change formData
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
         event.preventDefault();
         const formData = {login, password};
}
```

```
//handle value change events
<div className="form-element">
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value={login} onChange={handleLogin} required />
</div>

<div className="form-element">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value={password} onChange={handlePassword} required />
</div>
```

This ensures the form fields are not sent as `undefined` to the server.

Comment: I've figured out that the entire req.body is undefined, but I'm now trying to figure out what is going on. The body-parser is installed and properly configured.